# keep a loaded portion of an external HTML file with jQuery load()

Tags: jquery, load, droppable

What I have is 1 droppable div (dropZone) and several draggables.
The draggables are HTML code snippets that when dropped in the dropZone, render the html code in it. (the HTML code is stored in an external html file with ID's)
What happens is, when I drop one draggable, it works fine. but it I drop another one, it clears the current code. 
any suggestions about how this could be done?

```
$("#dropZone").droppable({
    tolerance: 'touch',
    over: function() {
        $('.dragMe').addClass('red');
    },
    out: function() {
        $('.dragMe').removeClass('red');
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
        $(this).load('test.html #' + id);
    }
});
```

is there a way to keep the current code inside dropZone so when I drop another draggable in it adds to the code?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Load the file into an variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
jQuery.get('http://localhost/test.html', function(data) 
{ 
    alert(data); 
});
```

This will get the data then you can assign the data to a variable for use later. If you have multiple loads then just make an array that contains all the data and each time you load add it to the array.

EDIT: (in your case)

```
drop: function(event, ui) 
{
    var id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
    jQuery.get('http://localhost/test.html#' + id, function(data) 
    { 
        //store data as variable
        $(this).html(data);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Hi Nate, I've tried the code you gave me. The thing is, for some reason, when i drag the draggable into #dropZone it outputs all the content of test.html instead of the content of the specific ID...

Comment: @Inon30 ah your going to have to look for the ID in the data... I've never tried to get a file segment with jquery. I'll see if I can get something working.

Comment: thanks pal. I am not sure how to do this yet, but i'll keep looking. Thanks a lot for the help.